# automatic classification model selecion

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, data-analysis

i want to know is there any method by which the computer can decide which classification model to use ( Decision trees, logistic regression, KNN, etc. ) by just looking at the training data.

even just the math will be extremely helpful.

I am going to be writing this in python 3, so if there's any built method in scikit-learn or tensorflow for this purpose,it would be of great help.

Comment: This is usually called automl. This link might be useful http://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/

Answer (score 2):

This scikit learn tool kit solves it :

https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/index.html